# Is there any strict findAll function in BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I am using Python- 2.7 and BeautifulSoup

Apologies if I am unable to explain what exactly I want

There is this html page in which data is embedded in specific structure 
I want to pull the data ignoring the first block

But the problem is when I do-

```
self.tab = soup.findAll("div","listing-row")
```

It also gives me the first block which is actually (unwanted html block)-

```
("div","listing-row wide-featured-listing")
```

I am not using

`soup.find("div","listing-row")`

since I want all the classes named **"listing-row**" only in that entire page.

How can I ignore the class named  **"listing-row wide-featured-listing"**?

Help/Guidance in any form is appreciated. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2):

Or, you may make a [CSS selector](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) to match the class exactly to `listing-row`:

```
soup.select("div[class=listing-row]")
```

Demo:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> 
>>> data = """
... <div>
...     <div class="listing-row">result1</div>
...     <div class="listing-row wide-featured-listing">result2</div>
...     <div class="listing-row">result3</div>
... </div>
... """
>>> 
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
>>> print [row.text for row in soup.select("div[class=listing-row]")]
[u'result1', u'result3']
```

Comment: soup.select("div[class=listing-row]") Worked well. Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: Nice; didn't realise that using the explicit attribute selector forces it to do a full string match!

Answer (score 0):

You could just filter out that element:

```
self.tab = [el for el in soup.find_all('div', class_='listing-row')
            if 'wide-featured-listing' not in el.attr['class']]
```

You could use a custom function:

```
self.tab = soup.find_all(lambda e: e.name == 'div' and
                                   'listing-row' in e['class'] and
                                   'wide-featured-listing' not in el.attr['class'])
```

Comment: I am new to "lambda" topic in python have not used it. Currently the above answer worked well although I am thankful for your answer too. I can use it after I have an idea about lambda and its features.

Comment: @PallaviJoshi: a `lambda` is an expression that creates a function. You can mentally translate the pattern `lambda arguments: expression` to `def lambda_function(arguments): return expression`.

Comment: @PallaviJoshi: except you don't need to put the function definition on a separate line. In other words, a `lambda` lets you create an *inline* function that only returns the result of a single expression.

Comment: Now I am confused as to mark which answer as correct one. Since both are informative and helpful.

Comment: @PallaviJoshi: the choice is entirely yours. Flip a coin if you can't pick, or don't pick either (also a valid option).

Comment: Cool I won't pick any whoever reads from respective perception finds desired answer as correct one :) moreover I have less coins left :p