# Using select function in Beautifulsoup returns None value

Tags: python, python-2.7, css-selectors, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I am using Python-2.7 and BeautifulSoup

With reference to my [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34356912/is-there-any-strict-findall-function-in-beautifulsoup) question I am trying to get the contents from div tags which has almost similar name. Hence I require strict check on the class name of div tag.

Following is my code-

```
list = ['Link1','Link2','Link3','Link4',....etc]
for i in list:
    mech = Browser()
    mech.set_handle_robots(False)
    mech.set_handle_equiv(False)
    hadr = {'User-Agent':'Agent'}
    req = urllib2.Request(i,headers=hadr)
    try:
            pan = urllib2.urlopen(req)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(pan, "lxml") 
            tag1 = soup.select("div[class=profile-container abc-profile-container]")
            print "TAG_1",tag1
            tag2 = soup.select("div[class=profile-container]")
            print "TAG_2",tag2
    except Exception as e:
            print e
            print(type(e))
```

Further I wanted to specify is any random links from the list contains tag1's div class but its output is coming as blank.

All I want the links which have `("div[class=profile-container abc-profile-container]")` should accept tag1 and work accordingly instead of giving a blank list as output.

Comment: since you originally said `Guidance / Help in any form is appreciated` I recommend you look at `traceback.print_exc` instead of `print(e),print(type(e))`, It's wonderfully more informative.

Comment: Hi Thanks a lot but someone suggested me to edit it hence I did so. Although I will try this definitely

Comment: Well yeah, it attracts off topic comments like mine. :P

Answer (score 1):

Use [CSS Selectors](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) in `.select()`

```
tag1 = soup.select("div.profile-container.abc-profile-container")
tag2 = soup.select("div.profile-container")
```

Comment: I tried it but its giving me following output- `TAG_1 [] TAG_2[---the actual content---] `  The links having class from tag1 are not showing any contents as it shows for TAG_2[]

Comment: Are you sure there are `div` tags with both `profile-container` `abc-profile-container` classes in the soup? I tested both tag1 select and tag2 select for my test webpage and it worked perfect.

Comment: I pasted the entire output in notepad it shows `TAG_1[]     TAG_2[---actual content from div.profile-container-----]                        TAG_1[---actual content from div.profile-container.abc-profile-container-----]                                                                               TAG_2[---actual content from div.profile-container.abc-profile-container-----]`

Comment: Well, your output states that, you tested with 2 links, first link had `.profile-container` but not `.abc-profile-container` and second link had both of the classes. What else do you want to get? According to your question this is your desired output.

Comment: Its like one link has any of the above mentioned one class only not the both hence i made 2 separate tag_variables for it. I am unable to understand why it worked with 2nd tag and not with 1st wherein the 1st link contains the `profile-container abc-profile-container` class in it

Comment: If you can give me the links, I can test, but if it is working for 2nd link and not 1st then it clearly means 1st link does not have both the classes.